# Azure Mobile Services Connecting With Android App Getting java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.gson.GsonBuilder Error

Tags: android, azure, gson

1.I am Using Azure Mobile Services for Saving Data in cloud From Android Application.

2.Iam Getting Below Error:

**java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.gson.GsonBuilder**

Please Help me to solve this Issue.

```
   01-04 17:06:47.244 14795-14795/com.example.newapk E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    01-04 17:06:47.244 14795-14795/com.example.newapk E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.example.newapk, PID: 14795
    01-04 17:06:47.244 14795-14795/com.example.newapk E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.gson.GsonBuilder
    01-04 17:06:47.244 14795-14795/com.example.newapk E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.MobileServiceClient.createMobileServiceGsonBuilder(MobileServiceClient.java:192)
    01-04 17:06:47.244 14795-14795/com.example.newapk E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.MobileServiceClient.<init>(MobileServiceClient.java:179)
    01-04 17:06:47.244 14795-14795/com.example.newapk E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.MobileServiceClient.<init>(MobileServiceClient.java:158)
    01-04 17:06:47.244 14795-14795/com.example.newapk E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.example.newapk.UpdateLocation.onCreate(UpdateLocation.java:115)
    01-04 17:06:47.244 14795-14795/com.example.newapk E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2743)
    01-04 17:06:47.244 14795-14795/com.example.newapk E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1900(ActivityThread.java:151)
    01-04 17:06:47.244 14795-14795/com.example.newapk E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1415)
    01-04 17:06:47.244 14795-14795/com.example.newapk E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
    01-04 17:06:47.244 14795-14795/com.example.newapk E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    01-04 17:06:47.244 14795-14795/com.example.newapk E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5304)
    01-04 17:06:47.244 14795-14795/com.example.newapk E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    01-04 17:06:47.244 14795-14795/com.example.newapk E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    01-04 17:06:47.244 14795-14795/com.example.newapk E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824)
    01-04 17:06:47.244 14795-14795/com.example.newapk E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640)
    01-04 17:06:47.244 14795-14795/com.example.newapk E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

app.gradle File:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.newapk"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        // Enabling multidex support.
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }


    }

    repositories {
        flatDir {
            dirs 'aars'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.microsoft.azure:azure-mobile-services-android-sdk:2.0.3'
    compile 'com.microsoft.azure:azure-notifications-handler:1.0.1@jar'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
    compile 'com.google.guava:guava:16.0.1'
}
```